# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED office-JS

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, yo

I just created a new boilerplate Yo office Excel addin with React and typescript. It worked for a short time but than I got some strange errors:

[image: Failed to load resources]

My taskpane remains empty and I cannot find out why it does not work. What I tried so far:

1. Close the Node server and start again with "npm start"
2. "npm install" to make sure that all depencies where met.
3. Removed line by line the App code to find out if the error is related to a custom module

any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: The last error about favicon can be ignored. The 3rd is a side effect of the first two. The first two errors mean that some files of the Office JavaScript library cannot load from the CDN. This is probably a temporary network problem. At any rate, if the add-in worked before, changing it isn't going to fix this.

Comment: Hi Rick, Indeed it was a problem with the CDN! now I started it up again and it worked! Do you know a possiblility to load the references offline instead of using the CDN?

Comment: You can use the nuget package. See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/update-your-javascript-api-for-office-and-manifest-schema-version#updating-an-office-add-in-project-created-with-a-text-editor-or-other-ide

Comment: There's also and NPM package: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js#about-the-npm-package